# undefined method `request_uri' error when using Rest Client - trying to delete with Facebook Graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rest-client

I can trying to use [Rest Client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) to delete an object using the [Facebook Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

```
def delete_object
    temp = url_escape('https://graph.facebook.com/'+request_id+'?access_token='+token)
    p "temp is"
    p temp
    delete_attempt = RestClient.delete temp
end

private

def url_escape(string)
    string.gsub(/([^ a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/n) do
        '%' + $1.unpack('H2' * $1.size).join('%').upcase
    end.tr(' ', '+')
end
```

Console output:

```
temp is
"https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.facebook.com%2Fobject_id_here%3Faccess_token%3Daccess_token_here"
```

`object_id_here` & `access_token_here` used as placeholders here, the values are correct.

I get this error:

```
undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x00000104385a40>
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:60:in `execute'\n/
Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:31:in `execute'\n/
Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient.rb:80
```

Line 60 in [request.rb](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/request.rb) is the `transmit uri...` line in this method in Rest Client:

```
def execute & block
    uri = parse_url_with_auth(url)
    transmit uri, net_http_request_class(method).new(uri.request_uri, processed_headers), payload, & block
end
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: I'm getting the same error trying to use klout.com API